# sql syntax in ms. access and vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i want ask you about sql syntax in microsoft access.

what i want is :

```
kdploting kdsubject nmsubject nmlecture
kp001     km001        xx          a
kp001     km002        yy          b
kp001     km003        zz          c
```

mysql syntax is :

```
select distinct(d.kdploting), c.kdsubject, a.nmsubject, b.nmlecture 
from subject a, mstlecture b, 
transplotingdetail c, transplotingheader d 
where d.kdploting = 'kp001' 
and d.kdploting = c.kdploting 
and c.kdsubject = a.kdsubject 
and d.kdlecture = b.kdlecture;
```

result :

```
kdploting kdsubject nmsubject nmlecture
kp001     km001        xx          a
kp001     km001        xx          b
kp001     km001        xx          c
kp001     km002        yy          a
kp001     km002        yy          b
kp001     km002        yy          c
kp001     km002        zz          a
kp001     km002        zz          b
kp001     km002        zz          c
```

i don't want the result like this, so can somebody explain me why it can happend? and whats the correct sql query?

thanks guys!

note : i really need this query for my vb.net program, thanks guys!

here my table :

```
 subject 
    kdsubject nmsubject
    km001     xx
    km002     yy
    km003     zz

 mstlecture 
    kdlecture nmlecture
    kd001     a
    kd002     b
    kd003     c

 Transplotingdetail 
    kdploting kdmatakuliah
    kp001     km001
    kp001     km002
    kp001     km003
    kp002     km001
    kp002     km002
    kp002     km003
    ...

 transploting header 
    kdploting kdlecture
    kp001     kd001
    kp001     kd002
    kp001     kd003
    kp002     kd001
    kp002     kd002
    kp002     kd003    
    ...
```

## What i want is like this

```
kdploting kdsubject nmsubject nmlecture
kp001     km001        xx          a
kp001     km002        yy          b
kp001     km003        zz          c
```

Comment: You are missing alias on your last join condition. Can you edit and add that?

Comment: can you post sample data from all tables?

Comment: so what i should do? did you need example data from all my table?

Comment: i just inserted example of my data from all my table. Thanks

Comment: The DISTINCT clause is not a function and always applies to all the fields; i.e. you will get distinct combinations of field values over all the fields.

Comment: @user1533670 please take a look at the updated query. Sorry for getting back to you late. :) This query can be improved. Give it a try please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At convenience of usage, I have shortened/changed the table/subject names. But using the same data as your sample. The best part of SQL Server featuers are **`Row_Number()`** :) Since the query is being done in SQL Server I made use of it. SQL Server syntax are more aligned with MS ACCESS. So the most important part of the query is to make sure there's a ranking/numbering on the inner records based on distinct `subjectid` and `lectureid`. Please take a look at the

### * [SQLFIDDLE Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bf4f/3)

**Query:**

```
select y.did, x.lid, x.lname,
y.sid, y.sname from
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.lid) AS Row,
 a.lid, a.lname, b.did
from mstl a
left join (select distinct lid, did from 
           th) as b
on b.lid = a.lid
where b.did = 'kp001') as x
join
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.sid) AS Row,
 c.sid, c.sname, d.did
from subject c
left join (select distinct sid, did from 
           td) as d
on d.sid = c.sid
where d.did = 'kp001') as y
on x.row = y.row
;
```

Results:

```
DID     LID     LNAME   SID     SNAME
kp001   kd001   a       km001   xx
kp001   kd002   b       km002   yy
kp001   kd003   c       km003   zz
```

Comment: @user1533670 Please try out the query as well as reconfirm if you have really missed out that `km001` condition.

Comment: sorry i just put wrong desired result, what i want is 
<pre>
kdploting kdsubject nmsubject nmlecture
kp001     km001        xx          a
kp001     km002        yy          b
kp001     km003        zz          c
</pre>

Comment: i'm very sorry for my mistake,

Comment: i want sid is "km001", "km002", "km003"
thanks for your help.